# Magento:2 How to Image upload in custom module

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, module, admin, collection

Image upload working fine in tmp folder, then store in DB. I want to after saving data image stored in the base folder  pub/media/events
  [image]

```
var_dump($data);

" ["events_url"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(10) { ["name"]=> string(39) "Screenshot_from_2018-04-30_18-07-01.png" ["type"]=> string(9) "image/png" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpGvtNFv" ["error"]=> string(1) "0" ["size"]=> string(6) "744010" ["path"]=> string(45) "/var/www/html/magento8/pub/media/faq/tmp/icon" ["file"]=> string(39) "Screenshot_from_2018-04-30_18-07-01.png" ["url"]=> string(88) "http://127.0.0.1/magento8/pub/media/faq/tmp/icon/Screenshot_from_2018-04-30_18-07-01.png" ["cookie"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(5) "admin" ["value"]=> string(26) "tcq6loa96ki11qfiri6j2llua5" ["lifetime"]=> string(3) "900" ["path"]=> string(15) "/magento8/admin" ["domain"]=> string(9) "127.0.0.1" } ["previewType"]=> string(5) "image" } } ["events_date"]=> string(24) "2018-05-25T11:45:00.000Z" } ["form_key"]=> string(16) "H3xhipTLApQ77NfQ" }
```

Comment: Are you trying to upload from fontend ?

Answer (score 0):

not clear with your question, assuming you want to upload file in pub/media/event

try this

```
<?php
namespace VenderName\ModuleName\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;

class Post extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
protected $_objectManager;
protected $_storeManager;
protected $_filesystem;
protected $_fileUploaderFactory;

public function __construct(
  \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
  \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
  StoreManagerInterface $storeManager, 
  \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem, 
  \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $fileUploaderFactory)
{
    $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_filesystem = $filesystem;
    $this->_fileUploaderFactory = $fileUploaderFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
    $mediaDir = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath();
    $mediapath = $this->_mediaBaseDirectory = rtrim($mediaDir, '/');

    $uploader = $this->_fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'id_from_tamplatefile_of upload_control']);
    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
    $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
    $path = $mediapath . '/events/';
    $result = $uploader->save($path);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code in your custom module and modify as per your requirement.

> File path: app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Controller/Index/Upload.php

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Controller\Index;

class Upload extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    protected $_filesystem;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $fileSystem
    ) {
        $this->_filesystem = $fileSystem;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Upload and save image
     * 
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $result = array();
        if ($_FILES['test_image']['name']) {
            try {
                // init uploader model.
                $uploader = $this->_objectManager->create(
                    'Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader',
                    ['fileId' => 'test_image']
                );
                $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
                $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
                // get media directory
                $mediaDirectory = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
                // save the image to media directory
                $result = $uploader->save($mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath());
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                \Zend_Debug::dump($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the controller for the same in your custom module and use this code for image upload as per your requirements.

> code should be added at following path:-
> app/code/Companyname/Vendorname/Controller/Index/Index.php

```
<?php
namespace Companyname\Vendorname\Controller\Index;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;


class Index extends Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $uploaderFactory;
    protected $adapterFactory;
    protected $filesystem;
    protected $messageManager;
   
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
        AdapterFactory $adapterFactory,
        Filesystem $filesystem,
        ManagerInterface $messageManager
    )
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
        $this->adapterFactory = $adapterFactory;
        $this->filesystem = $filesystem;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {  
        // this folder will be created inside "pub/media" folder
        $imageFolderName = 'event/';
 
        // "my_custom_file" is the HTML input file name
        $inputFileName = 'image';
 
        try{
            $file = $this->getRequest()->getFiles($inputFileName);
            $fileName = ($file && array_key_exists('name', $file)) ? $file['name'] : null;
 
            if ($file && $fileName) {
                $target = $this->mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($imageFolderName); 
                /** @var $uploader \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader */
                $uploader = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => $inputFileName]);
                // set allowed file extensions
                $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg','png','jpeg']);
                // allow folder creation
                $uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
                // rename file name if already exists 
                $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                // upload file in the specified folder
                $result = $uploader->save($target);
                /*echo '<pre>'; print_r($result); exit;*/
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            //$this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please upvote these answer if useful